# In textarea, replace two \n with tab indent while typing

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, textarea

I am trying to replace two `\n\n` (so when enter is pressed twice) with a tab intend (`\t`)

If I write "bla bla bla [enter enter] bla bla bla bla bla [enter enter] bla bla", it doesn't implement the tab indents while I am still typing, however it applies when I click outside (unfocus textarea).

```
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="testVal"></textarea>
</div>
```

and vue:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    testVal: 'Val'
  },

  watch: {
    testVal(val) {
        this.testVal = val.replace(new RegExp('(\n){2,}', 'gim') , "\t");    
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a fiddle that you can observe the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/8gst4mrh/1/

What I actually want to achieve is, when user clicks enter two times, change it to tab indent

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your demo, `console.log(this.testVal)` logs the values with tabs.

Comment: But, it doesn't apply it inside the textarea. But when I click outside (unfocus textarea), it tabs get applied.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the reason for replacing `\n\n` with `\t` instead of handling `tab` key inside `textarea`?

Comment: @Traxo You are right actually. But they wanted this functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to be an issue with Vue version 1. [Your code works as expected using Vue v2.](https://jsfiddle.net/8gst4mrh/3/)

If you need to use that version of Vue, you should explicitly listen to the `input` event and call a method to update the value of `testVal`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    testVal: 'Val'
  },
  
  methods: {
    updateTestVal() {
      this.testVal = this.testVal.replace(new RegExp('(\n){2,}', 'gim') , "\t");    
      console.log(this.testVal)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="testVal" @input="updateTestVal"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! works like charm! I have another question. How would you do it if you wanted to keep `\n\n` but add indent after them?

Comment: This can get you started: `if (foo.slice(-2).match(/\n\n/)) { foo += '\t' }`. If you can't figure it out, I'd post another question